# How to show a "signed in" users' list of favorites

Tags: python, html, flask

I want to show a signed in users list of favorited cocktails in their profile, right now its showing ALL of the users favorites no matter who is signed in. I only want the signed in user to see the favorites that they have chosen in their account. Then when another user signs in, they see only their favorites, etc. Here is my code:

app.py

```
@app.route('/users/<int:user_id>')
def users_show(user_id):
    """Show user profile/favorites list."""
    
    user = User.query.get_or_404(user_id)

    favorites = Favorite.query.all()
    
  
    return render_template('users/show.html', user=user, favorites=favorites)

@app.route('/add-favorite', methods=["GET", "POST"])
def add_favorite():
    """Adds a cocktail to the users favorites list"""

    if not g.user:
        flash("Access denied, you need to sign up/in first!", "danger")
        return redirect("/")

    else:
        
        form = AddFavoriteForm()

    favorite = Favorite.add_favorite(
        cocktail_id =form.cocktail_id.data,
        cocktail_name = form.cocktail_name.data,
        cocktail_thumbnail=form.cocktail_thumbnail.data,
        user_id = session[CURR_USER_KEY]
    )
    db.session.commit()
    
    return redirect(f"/users/{g.user.id}")
```

show.html

```
{% for favorite in favorites %}

      <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
        <img src="{{ favorite.cocktail_thumbnail }}" class="card-img-top" alt="">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title">{{ favorite.cocktail_name }} </h5>
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-secondary" onclick="openGalleryModal('{{ favorite.cocktail_id }}')">How do I make it?</a>
        </div>
      </div>

      {% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`favorites = Favorite.query.all()` returns all Favorites. If you want to get only user's favorites - you need to filter them.

Something like `favorites = Favorite.query.filter(Favorite.user_id == user.id).all()`
More info here https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.Query.filter